# nginx redirect http to https on localhost

Tags: redirect, nginx, https, localhost

I'm testing nginx locally as a reverse proxy

I want to redirect wildcard subdomain http to https

The subdomains are handled programmatically in the application

```
    server {
        listen         80;
        server_name ~^(.*)\.localhost$;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen  443 ssl;
        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_min_length  1000;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k; 

        server_name ~^(.*)\.localhost$;
        # SSL Certs
        ssl_certificate /path/to/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/server.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3333;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

accessing https directly from the chrome works fine
accessing http does literally nothing, not even a page refresh

Comment: Have you tried using `$host` rather than `$server_name`. I am not sure what value `$server_name` is set to when the `server_name` directive is a regular expression.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what I should change in the config above?